# unicode string vs. character in regular expressions

Tags: python-3.x

From a source I get strings like defined in the example code.

I need to replace the hyphen (is between the T and the D of the string: T[hyphen]DP[minus]O) with ASCII minus to avoid any trouble using the data. It is hard to see if you use the "wrong" font.

And there are some other characters like en-dash and em-dash, which have to be replaced.

I got a list of unicode strings from a colleague to be replaced (hope they are correct...) and I am not very familiar with that.

I wrote a small snippet to test my replacement , but it was not working, so I tried to replace the hyphen "literally".

Why is re.sub() not working using the utf-8 coding?

```
import re

def main():
    String = 'T‐DP-0'
    Hyphen = '‐'
    RegexReplace = (
    ('UTF8 HYPHEN ', u'\xe2\x80\x90', u'\x2d'),
    ('UTF8 EN DASH', u'\xe2\x80\x93', u'\x2d'),
    ('UTF8 EM DASH', u'\xe2\x80\x94', u'\x2d'),
    ('literal     ', Hyphen         , u'\x2d'),
  )
    print (Hyphen.encode('utf-8'))
    print (String,ord(String[1]))
    for Name,Regex,Replace in RegexReplace:
        if re.search(Regex,String): 
            print ('  ==>',Name, 'found')
        else:
            print ('  ==>',Name, 'not found')

        String = re.sub(Regex,Replace,String)
    print (String,ord(String[1]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a running code after some research, I have to use a binary string using encode/decode.

```
import re

def main():
    String = 'T‐DP-0'
    Hyphen = '‐'
    RegexReplace = (
    ('UTF8 HYPHEN ', b'\xe2\x80\x90', b'\x2d'),
    ('UTF8 EN DASH', b'\xe2\x80\x93', b'\x2d'),
    ('UTF8 EM DASH', b'\xe2\x80\x94', b'\x2d'),
  )
    print (Hyphen.encode('utf-8'))
    print (String,ord(String[1]))
    BString = String.encode('utf-8')
    for Name,Regex,Replace in RegexReplace:
        if re.search(Regex,BString): 
            print ('  ==>',Name, 'found')
        else:
            print ('  ==>',Name, 'not found')

        BString = re.sub(Regex,Replace,BString)
    String=BString.decode(encoding='ascii')
    print (String,ord(String[1]))
```